# removing an edge from an adjacency list graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph

I'm playing with [this code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-and-its-representations/) which doesn't include a `remove_edge` method.

My attempt looks like this:

```
def remove_edge(self, src, dest):
    new_graph = []
    for i in range(self.V):
        node = self.graph[i]
        while node is not None:
            if i == src and node.vertex == dest:
                new_graph.append(AdjNode(src))
            elif i == dest and node.vertex == src:
                new_graph.append(AdjNode(dest))
            else:
                new_graph.append(node)
            node = node.next
    self.graph = new_graph
```

... but it causes index errors when I call has_edge later on. I assumed that adding a new node without `next` values would work here, but I need to do something different.

Here is the full code:

```
class AdjNode:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.vertex = data  # int
        self.next = None  # behave like a linked list node


class AdjGraph:
    def __init__(self, num_vertices):
        self.V = num_vertices
        self.graph = [None] * self.V

    # Function to print the graph
    def print_graph(self):
        for i in range(self.V):
            print("Adjacency list of vertex {}\n head".format(i), end="")
            temp = self.graph[i]
            while temp:
                print(" -> {}".format(temp.vertex), end="")
                temp = temp.next
            print(" \n")

    def add_edge(self, src, dest):
        # undirected...
        node = AdjNode(dest)
        node.next = self.graph[src]
        self.graph[src] = node

        node = AdjNode(src)
        node.next = self.graph[dest]
        self.graph[dest] = node

    def has_edge(self, src, dest):
        for i in range(self.V):
            node = self.graph[i]
            while node is not None:
                if i == src and node.vertex == dest:
                    return True
                if i == dest and node.vertex == src:
                    return True
                node = node.next
        return False


# tests:
graph = AdjGraph(5)
graph.add_edge(0, 1)
graph.add_edge(3, 1)

print(graph.has_edge(1, 3))  # True, as expected
graph.remove_edge(1, 3)
print(graph.has_edge(1, 3)) # expecting False here but I get an error:


  File "~\Desktop\pytester.py", line 96, in <module>
    print(graph.has_edge(1, 3))
  File "~\Desktop\pytester.py", line 64, in has_edge
    node = self.graph[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Strange: that `has_edge` implementation you based your code on is highly inefficient for no reason.  It’s also pretty much unrelated to a sensible `remove_edge`, so I’m not sure what to answer here that’s not a complete rewrite of the latter function.

Comment: I know that an edge query takes longer in adjacency list graphs than a matrix representation, but I didn’t know it was unnecessarily inefficient. Would the graph still be considered an adjacency list graph if I stored a dict of vertex (int keys) to edge mappings (list of ints) and traversed that instead?

Comment: It’s still an adjacency list regardless of its container, but the inefficiency isn’t about the container type.  Why would you look at *all* adjacency lists when you know the endpoints you’re looking for?

Comment: My assumption is that the GeeksfForGeeks guys write the code in another language like java or c++ using a linked list which takes O(n) to search and they don’t optimize it because they’re trying to demonstrate the trade offs in efficiency.

Comment: But that code exaggerates the inefficiency of that approach by a factor of half the number of vertices in the graph, which is madness.  My (sadder) assumption is that no one checked their work over there.